# How to set different locales in android?

Tags: android, localization, internationalization

In my application, I need to display strings according to user locale selection. So, I put my `strings.xml` in `values-en`, `values-ko`, etc. How can I set locale us, australia i.e; `values-en_US`, `values-en_AU`? But it's throwing an error? Can any one tell me how to set these locales in my code?

Answer (score 10):

Use `res/values-en-rUS/` (replacing the `_` with `-r`).

Comment: i am not getting error, am getting default strings on application , where i selected locale from custom locale ,  i need korean so i selected ko_KR , i kept Stings.xml in values-ko-rKR , but still am getting strings ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear with your question but if you are not sure as what name you need to for a specified locale refer to these links

http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/java/util/Locale.html

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/web/localizing-android-apps-draft

Android by default will take the resources from respective language that has been selected on the device/stimulator.

Answer (score 0):

There is International Standard for Locale.....like values-en for English....values-ko for Korean...You cant modify the standard..It would work if you keep the folder name as values-ko.